# How to redirect non admin user after login

Tags: redirect, login, user-roles

I have a custom user role on the site. I also have a login hook to redirect users to the home page. When an admin/editor logs in this works fine (although ultimately I would like them to redirect to the dashboard).

When a member of the custom user role logs in they get redirected to a 404. The admin/editor users get the editor frame around the page, so I assume what is happening is that when it tries to apply this for my custom role it finds that the user doesn't have rights to view the editor frame and so passes them on to a 404.

How do I get the users in my custom role to redirect to the normal (editorless) version of the page?

Edit:

The redirect hook I am using is this

```
function custom_login_redirect() {
   return home_url();
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect');
```

By edit frame, I mean that I see the site homepage but it has the WordPress wp-admin wp-adin header above it.

Comment: there's no code in your question, did you forget to include it? Use the edit link to include the missing code, as well as details on your custom roles. Also can you be more specific what you mean by the editor frame? There is more than one post/page editor in WordPress can you be more specific? Use the edit link under the question tags to add the missing info

Comment: @TomJNowell I've made the edits you have requested

Comment: Remove the quotes from around `home_url()` — as it stands you're redirecting the user to the literal URL `home_url()` (which probably ends up becoming `https://example.com/home_url()`, which should 404). If you're trying to hide the admin bar (the bar at the top of WordPress front- and back-end pages that appear for logged-in users), you can use the [`show_admin_bar` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/show_admin_bar/).